# How to Parse and Read the json data in scala and form a string by iterating through the values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to parse this json data and then read values under Orders element. My final goal is to read all the keys available under order element and then create a string by concatenating the values. E.g under Orders i have orderid,customerid and orderprice. i want for form an string with its values "order_id,customers.customerIdorder.price.charge,

```
{"Orders":{"orderid":"order_id","customerId":"customers.customerId","orderprice":"order.price.charge"},"Products":{"productid":"product_id","productName":"products.productName"}}



import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._
import scala.util.parsing.json._
val jsonString="""{"Orders":{"orderid":"order_id","customerId":"customers.customerId","orderprice":"order.price.charge"},"Products":{"productid":"product_id","productName":"products.productName"}}""";
    val json_data = JSON.parseFull(jsonString);
```

After this i am not able to iteratively read the keys and create that concatenated string. Can someone help.

Comment: irrespective of how many keys are there inside Orders, i want to read all of them. Basically i dont want to hardcode the keys to read the values

Comment: why do you want like this ? any usecase

Comment: use case is: i have input data coming where 100 of attributes are there. I am defining a bi schema where only selected attributes will go to the reporting table. Since the input data is nested, in the BI schema i am defining the paths for each attribute. in main scala profile i can use this concatenated string in sql statement to read the input data.

Comment: ok, do you have array columns in this json ? if yes, how do you want to in concat

Comment: e.g customerId can be populated from customers.customerId from input file. So in the schema json. i have defined "customerId":"customers.customerId" . I want to read all the keys inside Orders and create the concatenated string using their values order_id,customers.customerIdorder.price.charge . Let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `ujson` & `upickle` json libraries like below to `spark`

```
spark-shell --packages "com.lihaoyi:ujson_2.12:3.1.4,com.lihaoyi:upickle_2.12:3.1.4"
```

```
val jsonString="""
{
    "Orders": {
        "orderid": "order_id",
        "customerId": "customers.customerId",
        "orderprice": "order.price.charge"
    },
    "Products": {
        "productid": "product_id",
        "productName": "products.productName"
    }
}
"""
```

Convert `json string` to `json` format using `ujson.read` method.

```
 val data = ujson.read(jsonString)
```

Below is the code to extract its keys & contact values using `,`.

```
data
.obj
.keys
.map{ key => 
   Map(key -> data.obj(key).obj.values.map(_.str).mkString(",")) 
}
```

Below is the output & use filter to filter specific key.

```
Set(Map(Orders -> order_id,customers.customerId,order.price.charge), Map(Products -> product_id,products.productName))
```

OR You can use `spark` to concat json values like below.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json                                                                                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"Orders":{"orderid":"order_id","customerId":"customers.customerId","orderprice":"order.price.charge"},"Products":{"productid":"product_id","productName":"products.productName"}}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> val schema = "Orders map<string,string>"
scala> val jsonExprs = s"""concat_ws(',',map_values(from_json(json, '${schema}').orders)) AS output"""
scala> df.selectExpr(jsonExprs).show(false)
+------------------------------------------------+
|output                                          |
+------------------------------------------------+
|order_id,customers.customerId,order.price.charge|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you create the df ? just spark.read.json ?

Comment: like this -> `Seq(jsonString).toDF("json")`

Comment: Thank you so much for helping here.. Is there way i can send the Order key in a variable to the df.select . i mean i want to get the Orders key in parameter, i will store that in a variable which i want to pass

Comment: updated answer, You can use variable as needed.. I have added `schema` & `jsonExpr` just to show you.